# Including jquery breaks my simple web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inexplicably, web pages that were rendering and functioning correctly have stopped working. As far as I know, I am using the same browser (Chrome v. 23.0.1271.64) that I was using before, same JQuery, etc. I tried upgrading JQuery to the latest version and I *still* have this problem.  When I click on "Read Later" I see the message "Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined index.html:14 onclick"

When I comment out the Jquery include, it works.

I've tried in Firefox and I get the same results.

Here's my web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Kanban2go API Test Page</title>
      <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"/>
      <script>
          function foo(event) {
              console.log("Foo!")
              return true;
          }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="submit" value="Read Later" onclick="foo(event);"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT:

Thanks for all the replies.  I up-voted all the answers pertaining to my question, but I can only accept one.

Comment: Script tags are not selfclosing.. you should add a closing tag `<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always** use `</script>`. Never self-close a script tag:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
          function foo(event) {
              console.log("Foo!")
              return true;
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"/>` should be `<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 4):

Script is not self closing tag

Change

```
<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"/>
```

To

```
<script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script>
```